# Combine column with NA's

Tags: r, merge, combiners

I have a data frame

```
data <- data.frame('a' = c('A','B','C','D','E'),
              'x' = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA),
              'y' = c(NA,NA,3,NA,NA),
              'z' = c(NA,NA,NA,4,NA))
```

It looks like this:

```
  a  x  y  z
1 A  1 NA NA
2 B  2 NA NA
3 C NA  3 NA
4 D NA NA  4
5 E NA NA NA
```

I expect to get a data like this:

```
  a  N
1 A  1
2 B  2
3 C  3
4 D  4
5 E NA
```

Thank you!

Comment: It is not an exact duplicate, pay attention to the 5th row, it remains as NA when all row elements are NA. If you follow the answer you linked, then the OP will lose that element (row 5).

Comment: Okay, not exact.  But close enough.

Comment: I would probably do something like `cbind(data[1],  N = data[-1][cbind(1:nrow(data), max.col(!is.na(data[-1])))])`

Answer (score 4):

A *dplyr* solution using `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
    mutate(N = coalesce(x, y, z)) %>%
    select(a, N)

  a  N
1 A  1
2 B  2
3 C  3
4 D  4
5 E NA
```

No need for `select` with `transmute`:

```
data %>%
    transmute(a, N = coalesce(x, y, z))
```

Comment: or just `data %>% transmute(a, N = coalesce(x, y, z))`

Comment: @alistaire I'm always forgetting about `transmute`, good thinking.

Comment: You could also use sql to do this easily - `library(sqldf); sqldf("select a, coalesce(x,y,z) as N from data")` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try something like this:

```
> result <- apply(data[, -1], 1, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, x[!is.na(x)]))
> data.frame(a=data[,1], N=result)
  a  N
1 A  1
2 B  2
3 C  3
4 D  4
5 E NA
```

Answer (score 1):

`pmax` seems to suggest itself here, which should be substantially quicker on large data compared to looping over each row:

```
do.call(pmax, c(data[c("x","y","z")],na.rm=TRUE) )
#[1]  1  2  3  4 NA

cbind(data["a"], N=do.call(pmax, c(data[c("x","y","z")],na.rm=TRUE) ))
#  a  N
#1 A  1
#2 B  2
#3 C  3
#4 D  4
#5 E NA
```