# Join two tables but fill common column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame `left` with columns `name` and `x`, and I want to match the missing `x` entries with the corresponding `name` entries from a data frame `right`:

```
left = data.frame(
  name = c("Bob", "Billy", "Roger", "Anna", "Kathy"),
  x = c(NA, NA, NA, 4, 5)
)

# > left
#   name  x
# 1 Bob   NA
# 2 Billy NA
# 3 Roger NA
# 4 Anna   4
# 5 Kathy  5

right = data.frame(
  name = c("Bob", "Billy", "Roger"),
  x = c(1, 2, 3)
)

# > right
#   name  x
# 1 Bob   1
# 2 Billy 2
# 3 Roger 3
```

A `left_join` gives me two columns

```
> left_join(left, right, by="name")
   name x.x x.y
1 Bob    NA   1
2 Billy  NA   2
3 Roger  NA   3
4 Anna    4  NA
5 Kathy   5  NA
```

But what I want is:

```
    name x 
1 Bob     1   
2 Billy   2   
3 Roger   3   
4 Anna    4  
5 Kathy   5
```

Can I do this with a join command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(left)[right, on = 'name', x := i.x]
left
#    name x
#1:   Bob 1
#2: Billy 2
#3: Roger 3
#4:  Anna 4
#5: Kathy 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Another one

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(left, right, "name") %>% 
  transmute(name, x=coalesce(x.x, x.y))
#    name x
# 1   Bob 1
# 2 Billy 2
# 3 Roger 3
# 4  Anna 4
# 5 Kathy 5
```

([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237123/combine-column-with-nas))

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution

```
> out <- na.omit(merge(left, right, by=c("name", "x"), all=TRUE))
> out[order(out$x),] # to get your same order
   name x
4   Bob 1
2 Billy 2
7 Roger 3
1  Anna 4
6 Kathy 5
```

Comment: (A minor thing:) This depends on `right` being able to fill all the missing values in `left`.